# Remove Trailing Slash from Footer Links added via addLink

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, footer-links

I have added several links in my layout.xml like this:

```
<action method="addLink" translate="label title">
     <label>XYZ</label>
     <url>xyz</url>
     <title>XYZ</title>
     <prepare>true</prepare>
</action>
```

These links will include a trailing slash while my sitemap will include them without the trailing slash. Since all other links in my store have no trailing slash, I am wondering, why links added via *addLink* will do. Is there a way to remove these trailing slashes?
I tried modifying *Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php* and *Mage\Core\Method\Url.php* to remove trailing slashes from all URLs but some ajaxFunctions will not work anymore if I do so, so I am looking for a way to only remove them from the addLink function.